# Identical version of all installed software across 100 Debian Systems

Tags: linux, debian, devops, cicd

For a Project I need to setup a system that guarantees that the exact same Version of Kernel and all Packages ist installed across about 100 Debian Systems. The systems can be accessed via ssh. And have some individual packages installed. They have all more or less the same server hardware.

I want to create a frozen version of a test system where I put all packages on hold. I will test that everything is running and than deploy the same versions of all packages to the 100 other systems. The frozen state will be updated from time to time and deployed again. The unified version needs to stay like it is. Updates should not install automatically, at least not from official mirrors. The Setup so far contains one testsystem and one deploy system. The deploy system takes the frozen state from the testsystem and deploys it to the 100.

The solution should be rock solid and as simple as possible and as complex as necessary.
I had different approaches but would like to hear your thoughts about it.

-Creating a Debian Package that has all other needed packages as dependency with the exact version.
-Creating a selections file from the Testsystem.
-Setting up an individual debian mirror that only delivers the packages i want. The sources.list for the 100 needs to be changed one time but after that no manual installation needed anymore and updates will be applied automatically from my mirror only.

I consider using either Ansible or a shell script for the deployment/mirror server. For deployment and also for getting the "frozen state" from the test system.

Again requirements are:

- Rock solid
- Simple as possible
- exact same version of all installed software for the 100 running systems

Ok thats it so far.
I appreciate your thoughts and would like to hear pro and cons of the different approaches.

I thought a lot about what will be best and missing experience to decide.

Comment: I'm working on Reliza Hub that may help in solving this problem - particularly, create a "frozen state" bundle version and then target system would pull this via CycloneDX SBOM. If you'd like to discuss, DM me at devopscommunity.org discord.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest looking towards solutions that do not require a lot of coding and also that do not "fire and forget" like Ansible.

We are using qbee.io  (https://qbee.io/) platform for similar things for more than 1 year.

qbee allows you to deploy only the packages you want and then keeps the state.
If a package or package config was changed on the device (let's say auto-updated by OS or by a user) - it has a self-healing, so it will restore the previous state defined in their configuration management.

qbee supports custom package repos: see the docs: https://qbee.io/docs/qbee-define-repositories.html

The way we use it:

We split our infra into the groups - dev and prod.

We integrated qbee into our GitHub CI pipeline via their REST API, so the once the new package is ready - it auto-deployed to the dev devices. You can use their UI for that too.

Once we are happy - we update the package file and then it is automatically distributed to all prod devices. Qbee reports if the installation is successful or failed.

As a bonus, you also get monitoring, reporting, audit, and a remote console in case you want to get access to a device.

We tried several alternative solutions before qbee, but none of them gave us the full package.

Comment: That sounds good I will check it out. O e additional requirement is although there is a prod and Dev we need a rollback functionality. My thought was to create an overlayfs for that.